# Need help to start a new activity from within a viewpager class in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a sliding tab interface that consists of 2 layouts. On the second layout I have a button that must start an activity that will set the content view to a new layout. I get the following error when I try to start the activity:

***An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Fragment.StartActivity(Intent)'***

The `ViewPager` class looks like this:

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter 
{

    List<string> items = new List<string>(); //This list called items contains the items that we add below

    public SamplePagerAdapter() : base() //This method creates the tabs on top
    {
        items.Add("Productivity Optimization");
        items.Add("Remote Health Monitoring");

    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; } //This method returns the count of the tabs
    }


    public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj)
    {
        return view == obj;
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.PO, container, false);
        //***Original code***
        //View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);

        //container.AddView(view);

        //TextView txtTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_title);
        //int pos = position + 1;
        //txtTitle.Text = pos.ToString();

        //return view;
        //***end of original code***

        //This is where you set which layout to display in which order
        if (position == 0)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.PO, container, false);
            container.AddView(view);

        }

        if (position == 1)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.RHM, container, false);
            container.AddView(view);

            //New test button that should start the web browser activity
            var btnRep = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnReport);
            btnRep.Click += BtnRep_Click;


        }

        return view;

    }
}
```

And the button click method where the error occurs looks like this:
(The error is with `StartActivity`)

```
private void BtnRep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var BrowserIntent = new Intent(Application.Context,typeof(ReportBrowserActivity));

    **StartActivity(BrowserIntent);**

}
```

I am aware that there are a lot of similar questions and answers here for this problem, but I am new to Xamarin and I just can't seem to get this right.

Any help or a nudge in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: The line within your click method ( `BrowserIntent` ) can you try replacing `Application.Context` with just `Context`?

Comment: @Pilatus, thanks for getting back to me. Yes, I did try this as well, but then I get the following error: **'Context' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.** This is after I change the line to`var BrowserIntent = new Intent(Context,typeof(ReportBrowserActivity));`

Comment: That's probably because you're calling `Context` from your activity in that case `this` equals the `Context` of your `Activity` try replacing `Context` with `this`.

Comment: @Pilatus, that was how I originally had it written, but it kept giving my the following error: **CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'JoySmart_Solutions.SlidingTabsFragment.SamplePagerAdapter' to 'Android.Content.Context'**

Comment: You need a reference to an `Activity`. If you're using a `Fragment` to show the `ViewPager` this reference is made and can be accessed through the property `Activity`.

Comment: @Pilatus, thanks, I have come to the realization that this is the case, but no matter how I try to get a reference to the activity, I just keep hitting a brick wall. I know this sounds dumb, but how do I get the reference to the activity?

Comment: Can you show where you create the `SamplePageAdapter`? You could pass it through the constructor?

Comment: @Pilatus, is this what you were looking for: `public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            mSlidingTabScrollView = view.FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs); 
            mViewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager); 
            mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(); 

            mSlidingTabScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;

            
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object reference is needed in order to call it's (non-static) methods. Creating a reference is done with the following code:

```
var myObject = new myObject()
```

You can pass this reference through the constructor of `SamplePagerAdapter`. I'm assuming you're creating the `SamplePagerAdapter` within a `Fragment` ( since `OnViewCreated` isn't available in an `Activity` )

```
mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(Activity);
```

The constructor will then look like:

```
private Activity _activity;

public SamplePagerAdapter(Activity activity) : base() //This method creates the tabs on top
{
    _activity = activity;
    items.Add("Productivity Optimization");
    items.Add("Remote Health Monitoring");

}
```